# Why does installing this module fails?

Tags: commerce, installation

I used `composer create-project drupalcommerce/project-base commerce --stability dev`, as suggested from [Installation|Drupal Commerce](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/install-update/installation)  Installation starts normally, but after I am asked for the database credentials, the installation fails with the following error. (The server document directory for https://pood2.veskimees.eu/ is /commerce/web.)

> Error: Class "Drupal\shortcut\Entity\Shortcut" not found in commerce_base_install() (line 25 of profiles/contrib/commerce_base/commerce_base.install).
> commerce_base_install() call_user_func_array('commerce_base_install', Array) (Line: 392)
> Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invoke('commerce_base', 'install', Array) (Line: 343)
> Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array, ) (Line: 83)
> Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array, )  (Line: 1653)
> install_install_profile(Array) (Line: 694)
> install_run_task(Array, Array) (Line: 565)
> install_run_tasks(Array, NULL) (Line: 118)
> install_drupal(Object) (Line: 48)

What's wrong?

Comment: That module is missing.You should open up a ticket in the issue queue for that distribution.

Comment: I've never installed it that way, but certainly looks like there is a module missing in your code base. The way I installed it, is to install Drupal 8 or 9 first and then run `composer require 'drupal/commerce'`.

Comment: Ok, second attempt worked fine when I changed PHP ver from 8.0 to 7.4 -- so, problem solved...